# SelfControl application for Mac OS X won't reset

Tags: macos, selfcontrol

I used [SelfControl for Mac](http://visitsteve.com/made/selfcontrol/) two days ago, in which I have put my Mac to sleep while it was still on. Yet it was working fine until today when I tried to use it. The black countdown box appeared and said `00:00:00`.

It won't reset and let me add time.

I've already tried restarting my computer, shutting down my computer, and downloading the application again. What are my options to fix this, if any?

Answer (score 2):

### The official fix:

From [the official FAQ](https://github.com/slambert/selfcontrol/wiki/FAQ):

> **Q: SelfControl's timer is at 00:00 but it hasn't stopped blocking and I can't start a new block. And I'm freaking out!!!**
>
> This is a bug that happens occasionally. Get in touch via visitsteve.com/contact and we'll send you a fix.

So, there's your fix!

---

### The manual fix:

Judging from the [code itself](https://github.com/slambert/selfcontrol/blob/master/HostFileBlocker.m) it seems that it's just the `/etc/hosts` file that is being edited to block sites from being accessed. If that's the case, open up a Terminal, enter:

```
sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.fail
sudo cp /etc/hosts.bak /etc/hosts
```

This should restore the backup that SelfControl created for you.

If that doesn't work, you can also try to manually edit the hosts file and remove all blocked sites:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

The blocked sites will start after the line with

```
# BEGIN SELFCONTROL BLOCK
```

and go until

```
# END SELFCONTROL BLOCK
```

So, just remove all these. Press `Ctrl-O`, then `Enter` to overwrite the file. Note that your hosts file should always include the following at the top:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```