# Safari Self Control won't unblock websites

Tags: macos, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SelfControl application for Mac OS X won't reset](https://superuser.com/questions/350400/selfcontrol-application-for-mac-os-x-wont-reset)

I added some sites to Self Control.

Now that the time period is up, I cannot access these sites anymore, like I couldn't during the time.

I tried restarting Safari and emptying my cache, along with blocking it again for one minute and waiting for that time to finish.

Answer (score -1):

From what i gather you can get rid of it by restarting if that doesn't work try removing the application? I assume your using mac if you on safari. Try [this](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to remove the app. Could be bug with the app not sure never used it before.

***EDIT: I am in no way suggesting remove safari just the broken app that wont allow you to access the sites.***

***EDIT2: As confirmed below in the comments you will need to go in and edit the hosts to make sure its back to normal. [Linky](https://superuser.com/questions/350400/selfcontrol-application-for-mac-os-x-wont-reset) This post shows the situation in more detail.***

Bill

Comment: Removing Safari, which is more or less built into OS X? Doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Im not suggesting remove safari im suggesting removing the app that is broken.

Comment: I see now — well, that's a little more complicated than that. I've covered this here: [SelfControl application for Mac OS X won't reset](http://superuser.com/questions/350400/selfcontrol-application-for-mac-os-x-wont-reset)

Comment: Right so you just go in and edit your hosts file. Sorry about the confusion earlier. Updated answer. Thanks